# Wildcards and IShellFolder enumeration?

Tags: shell, winapi, com

I wanted to try moving away from `FindFirstFile()`/`FindNextFile()` and work directly with `IShellFolder` to get the list of files.  The reason is that I then want to get an `IShellItem` via `SHNCreateItemFromIDList()` for each file and I'd have everything needed to pass to the function.  If I used the file paths functions, I think I would need to build the full path each time before passing to `SHCreateItemFromParsingName()`, but I'll ask another question specific to that.

My question here is limited to using `IShellFolder` to enumerate the files and folders using wildcards.  Is there something built-in to do that, or do you have to do your own file matching?

TIA!!

Comment: `IShellFolder` enumeration does not support wildcards. You have to filter the child items manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use IShellFolder to filter, but you can use the search facilities built into the Shell to do the same thing programmatically, as you would do using the Windows Explorer UI.

For example, you can type something like *ext:.txt* in the search box in the right corner, it means you want to filter for all files with a *.txt* extension:

[image]

This is some C++ sample code somewhat equivalent (I've removed error checks at each line but make sure you test all possible errors):

```
int main()
{
  CoInitialize(NULL);
  {
    CComPtr<ISearchFolderItemFactory> search;
    CComPtr<IShellItem> item;
    CComPtr<IShellItemArray> items;
    CComPtr<IQueryParserManager> mgr;
    CComPtr<IQueryParser> parser;
    CComPtr<IQuerySolution> solution;
    CComPtr<ICondition> condition;
    CComPtr<IShellItem> searchItem;
    CComPtr<IEnumShellItems> enumItems;

    // create search folder factory
    search.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SearchFolderItemFactory);

    // create d:\temp shell item and set search folder scope to it
    SHCreateItemFromParsingName(L"d:\\temp", NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&item));
    SHCreateShellItemArrayFromShellItem(item, IID_PPV_ARGS(&items));
    search->SetScope(items);

    // create the query parser manager
    mgr.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_QueryParserManager);
    mgr->CreateLoadedParser(L"", 0, IID_PPV_ARGS(&parser));

    // parse an ms-search expression
    parser->Parse(L"ext:.txt", NULL, &solution);

    // get the condition the parser has built for us
    solution->GetQuery(&condition, NULL);

    // give the condition to the search folder factory
    search->SetCondition(condition);

    // get the search result back as a shell item (a virtual folder) and enumerates it
    search->GetShellItem(IID_PPV_ARGS(&searchItem));
    searchItem->BindToHandler(NULL, BHID_EnumItems, IID_PPV_ARGS(&enumItems));

    do
    {
      CComPtr<IShellItem> child;
      ULONG fetched;
      HRESULT hr2 = enumItems->Next(1, &child, &fetched);
      if (!fetched)
        break;

      // get the display name (for example)
      CComHeapPtr<WCHAR> name;
      child->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_NORMALDISPLAY, &name);
      wprintf(L"item: %s\n", name);

      CComHeapPtr<WCHAR> path;
      child->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &path);
      wprintf(L" path: %s\n", path);
    } while (TRUE);
  }
  CoUninitialize();
  return 0;
}
```

The **search-ms** language is quite powerful. Its syntax is available here: [Querying the Index with the search-ms Protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/search/-search-3x-wds-qryidx-searchms)

Comment: Thanks, I had seen something about `ISearchFolderItemFactory` in some samples of other things.  But good to have documented here on exactly how to do it.  Although, it does look like a lot of steps/work in the raw without a easy to use class over the top of it all.

Answer (score 0):

The shell API provides enumeration, but without any filtering or wildcard facilities akin to those of `FindFirstFile()`/`FindNextFile()`.

Therefore, when using shell enumeration functionality, you must filter the items manually.