# return ATL Com Interface From COM Method

Tags: com, atl

i returned an ATL COM Interface from another CO Method from C++ to C#,
but I don't know how correctly I should manage the lifetime of the object that I created from c++, should I cache it and release it when the main interface released?

Comment: You should read the official doc thoroughly https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/managing-the-lifetime-of-an-object and after that post some code as it depends on your code (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Note that when using ATL, you should always use ATL's smart pointers (CComPtr,etc.). When properly used, you almost never have to use AddRef or Release anymore.

Comment: is "CoCreateInstance" create a smart pointer ?

Comment: No, a smart pointer is variable you create in your code. You can pas that variable as an output to CoCreateInstance. You can have a look at this for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/56544670/403671 to see how it's used in ATL context.